# Why is the aliased Model object not accessible from a jsp include?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jspinclude

I have a Model object ("`foo`") added to the ModelMap in the MVC controller:

Spring MVC Controller:

```
Foo foo = new Foo("FooName");
model.addAttribute("foo", foo);
return "foo";
```

I can call properties of the object in `foo.jsp`. I also set an alias for the `foo` object so that `genericFoo` can access the object - `genericFoo` expects the object to be called `genericFoo`.

foo.jsp:

```
<c:out value="${foo.name}"/> <!-- Displays "FooName" -->
<c:set var="genericFoo" value="${foo}"/>
<jsp:include page="genericFoo.jsp" />
```

However, `genericFoo.jsp` does not display properties of the object.

Why not?

genericFoo.jsp:

```
<c:out value="${genericFoo.name}"/> <!-- No value displayed displayed -->
```

Answer (score 4):

Because `<jsp:include>` does a dynamic include (it sort of dispatches the request to the included JSP). And `<c:set>` stores the object inside a page-scoped attribute. By definition, page-scoped attributes are only visible from the page which defined them.

Solutions:

1. Use a static include: `<%@include file="..."/>` rather than a dynamic one
2. put the attribute in a request scoped attribute: `<c:set var="genericFoo" value="${foo}" scope="request"/>`.

Comment: Adding scope="request" resolved a similar problem for me. Awesome!! Thanks.